# Boot Raspberry Pi Pico from XIP QSPI Flash

Tags: flash, raspberry-pi-pico, qspi

I am trying to boot a Pico from an external NOR flash module (Diligent Pmod SF3), but I can't find any information on how to configure the bootloader to do it. I looked at the documentation, but I'm confused about how to actually use those functions. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably a question for the raspberry pi forums -- have a look there: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=313306